# React v16- d3 v4, when using mouse from d3-selection will get, TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, event-handling, dom-events

Using **d3** with **React** and importing mouse from d3-selection

```
import { selectAll, select, mouse } from 'd3-selection';
```

when trying use : `mouse(e.target) or mouse(select('.element'))` in the component, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null
./node_modules/d3-selection/src/sourceEvent.js.__webpack_exports__.a
node_modules/d3-selection/src/sourceEvent.js:5
  2 | 
  3 | export default function() {
  4 |   var current = event, source;
> 5 |   while (source = current.sourceEvent) current = source;
  6 |   return current;
  7 | }
  8 |
```

The project created using **react-create-app**, seems source event is not accessed?...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution after some researching is this, as I'm not using d3-events, we should pass the event through the call to fix the problem...

```
var mouse = function(node) {
  var event = sourceEvent();
  if (event.changedTouches) event = event.changedTouches[0];
  return point(node, event);
};
```

**d3.mouse** does not accept event as arguments, but if you read the source code, you can find another function which gets called through **mouse()**, to return the value and it accepts event as an argument, this function called **clientPoint()**.

So instead of using **mouse()**, use **clientPoint()**...

In my case this worked:

```
import { selectAll, select, clientPoint } from 'd3-selection';
```

And:

```
myFunction(e){
  console.log(clientPoint(e.target, e));
}
```

I passed both element and event in this case as clientPoint (called point in the code, but exported as clientPoint) will accept (node, event) as you see in the source code:

```
var point = function(node, event) {
  var svg = node.ownerSVGElement || node;

  if (svg.createSVGPoint) {
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = event.clientX, point.y = event.clientY;
    point = point.matrixTransform(node.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    return [point.x, point.y];
  }

  var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [event.clientX - rect.left - node.clientLeft, event.clientY - rect.top - node.clientTop];
};
```

Hope this help somebody else using React v16 with D3 v4...

Comment: +1 for finding clientPoint(), first time I see it here at S.O. This is a new method in D3, which was released on 22 Nov 2017, barely 1 month ago (I know that because, as a D3 developer, I keep tracking the new releases).

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, yes was something helpful if using D3 in modular way or with frameworks like React or Angular,  I see, you have d3 as top tag! nice :)

Comment: Thank you @Alireza, for me the event was undefined when using svg.on("mousemove", ..) so was clientX and clientY. Adding an eventlistener solved the issue:
`svg.addEventListener("mousemove", ...);`